# How do I get Pi3 + Plex Media server to recognize my attached USB storage device?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, media-server

I cannot get Plex to recognize or read my directory when pointing it to my attached storage device. Plex doesn't see the folder or contents of the drive.

I have attempted to change permissions of the drive and files in the command line, to no avail:

```
cd /media/my_external_drive
```

sudo chmod -R -v 777 *

```
cd /media/my_external_drive
sudo chown -R -v my_username:my_username *
```

The commands worked, and I received the appropriate success messages but Plex still refuses to recognize the folders & files.

My PI3 is running Raspbian Jessie, and has Plex Media Server installed. I am using an externally powered hard drive to store media on. This drive is formatted FAT32, and the files were transferred from my PC library to the drive.

Comment: What steps did you take to get this far?  Can you access Plex from your web browser and see the content there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format your hard drive as EXT4 (this allows you to change permissions as needed). Then connect your drive, launch terminal and input the following command:

```
sudo chown -R myusername:my_username <mount_point_of_your_drive>
```

For my system, this looked like this:

```
sudo chown -R pi:pi /media/pi/NASHDD1
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin which is available in max2play for raspberry pi, by using this plugin you can have filesystem configuration:

https://www.max2play.com/en/portfolio/plugin-filesystem-mount/

Regards,
Mbydeen

Comment: Thank you I will try this out! Doesn't sound like it will meet my needs at first glance, but it might.